# How to write a 3 class program and have the main class trigger methods in the other two

Tags: java, class

I have to write a program with 3 classes and lots of different methods.
I've written a simpler example to try and get an idea where I am going wrong

First class (music) is defining  a music object with three data types.  And should have a method to print the contents of an array.

the second class (musicArray) has all the data for the array and should build the array when the third class tells it too.

the third class(searchclass) has the main method it should tell the second class to make the array then with user input search the array for songs that match the rating.

```
        import java.util.Arrays;

public class Music extends musicArray {

        private  String songTitle;
        private  double songLength;
        private  int rating;
        static String everything;

    public Music(String songTitle, double songLength, int rating) {
           this.songTitle = songTitle;
           this.songLength = songLength;
           this.rating = rating;
        }
    public  String getsongTitle()
    {
        return songTitle;
    }
    public  double getsongLength()
    {
        return songLength;
    }
    public    int rating()
    {
        return rating();
    }
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "music{"+ "songTitle= " + songTitle + ", songLength=  "
    + songLength + ",rating=" + rating + '}';
}
    public Music[] printsonglibrary(char[][] songDetails){

         for (int count = 0; count <= 6; count++)
             {
             return System.out.println(songDetails[count]);
             System.out.println(" ");
             }
         }
}

public class musicArray extends Searchclass{

    static Music song1 = new Music ("achy breaky", 5.32, 10);
    static Music song2 = new Music ("billy",1.2, 8 );
    static Music song3 = new Music ("hello", 1.5, 9 );
    static //Create array and make posistion 0 = song1

    Music[] songDetails ={song1,song2,song3};
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Searchclass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int count = 1; count <= songDetails.length; count++){
         system out put for debugging
          System.out.println(songDetails.length);
          System.out.println(songDetails[count - 1]);}
        }

        /* public String songSeach(){
        System.out.println("what rating of song do you want to search for?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int searchValue = keyboard.nextInt();
         if searchValue == rating in array use the printsonglibrary
        method in the music class to print the array entry
   */
        }
}
```

If I have the main method in the musicArray class I can print the array 
So the question is how do I make the Songdetails array available in the seachclass?

Comment: Is this a homework? Please tag so if it is.

Comment: @adarshr: I have added the homework tag

Comment: I would remove the nested class definition altogether.

Comment: @Jon: what nested class definition?

Comment: @ homework comments this is a simpler example of the program i'm working on but yeah i'll be using what I learn here for Homework.  Is that against forum rules?

Comment: @Bradley: no, it's not against the rules, but it's nice to know in advance as it changes our approach on how to guide you. When there is homework involved, that usually means that there are restrictions on what classes and techniques you can use. We also try to avoid giving full code solutions so as to avoid even the smell of cheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't directly expose any variables of one class to another. Instead consider giving the MusicArray class (note that by convention class names should begin with a capital letter) a public method, say `public void printOutSongDetails()` that would print out the contents of the array. Your main method can then call this method off of the MusicArray object that it has created.  e.g.,

**Edit 1**
Also, the Music class should most definitely **not** extend the MusicArray class for there is no way that a Music object should behave like a MusicArray object. And on the same token, MusicArray should not extend the SearchClass.

**Edit 2**
Note that there are several other significant issues with your code that each one would prevent it from compiling, and this suggests that you should modify how you program (if you can't use an IDE). Try to compile early and often, and only add new code to the program after fixing any compilation errors so that the current code base compiles.

**Edit 3**
A small code example of what I was describing above.

```
class SearchClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MusicArray musicArray = new MusicArray();
      musicArray.addMusic(new Music("Foobars Unit", 10.4, 5));
      musicArray.addMusic(new Music("Spamalot", 11.0, 7));
      //... etc ...

      musicArray.printOutSongDetails();
   }
}
```

Also, you'll probably not want those static Music variables but rather give MusicArray a method to add Music to its array, a public void addMusic method that accepts a Music object as a parameter.

Comment: You're right about the compilation issues.  Before I added the Searchclass I had the main in the MusicArray class and it was running fine. I write in eclipse.

Comment: @Bradley: If you write in eclipse, then the compilation issues should be almost non-existent since Eclipse will flag you any time there is code that won't compile.

Comment: @Bradley: see additional line to my Edit 1 above -- similarly MusicArray should not extend the SearchClass. Again a MusicArray object will not be expected to have SearchClass behaviors.

Comment: I took of both the extends and there is only one red flag to get rid of in the Music class which is on my printsonglibrary method which say cannot return a void result.

Comment: Good. Now I doubt that Music should even have that method as it belongs in your MusicArray class, right? And if it will print out the data in the array, then it should be declared a void method and return nothing.

Comment: Well my specs say that Music has to have a method that summarizes the data in the array to a string and sends it to the main class when its called. but I'd be happy to get it running first, then I can play around to get it on spec.

Comment: @Bradley: I'd like to see that spec. If Music is truly supposed to represent a *single song*, then it should have no knowledge that an array of it even exists. Rather Music should have a `toString()` method that allows it to display the information that it holds (the song title, length and rating), but that's about it.

Comment: the specs say that this method should be in the Music class. here is the specs adapted to this example "This method summarizes and returns (but does not print) the song data members in a reader friendly manner. It should return the summarized information as a string."

Comment: @Bradley: Just as I thought, the spec mentions nothing about an array. Rather it is suggesting something similar to what I suggested in my comment just above your last one.

Comment: I think with the information and tips you've given me I should be able to get this working.  Thank you very much for you time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make it public `public Music[] songDetails ={song1,song2,song3};`

A better way is to provide getter:

```
public Music[] getSongDetails() {
    return songDetails;
}
```

Comment: Is it better with regards to encapsulation?

Comment: Yeah. You want to prevent others from reassigning your array variable. You can't prevent them from modifying the array though - so even better would be to provide a member function to do whatever you want done with the array and don't expose it at all - but sometimes that's hard.

Comment: exactly, hence my answer, to give the method that holds this array a public method to print out the sing details. Incidentally, you can prevent users from modifying the array by creating a deep copy and returning the copy in your method above.

Comment: I put this Method in the MusicArray class 
And added this to the main arguments 
public static void main(String[] args, musicArray[] songDetails) And now i get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main"

Comment: you can't modify the main method like that. Instead create an instance of MusicArray in the body of the main method use this instance to access the array.

Comment: I went over to the java tutorials and read the entry "Understanding Instance and Class Members" but I'm not quite sure how to make the instance

Comment: what about `MusicArray ma = new MusicArray();`